# Disable Hover Effects on resize using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok so Im new to jQuery and a little confused how to achieve my goal here. The goal is whenever the browser is less than 780px wide I want to disable all hover effects. So I did a lot of research and still cant figure out a specific way that works for me, though I have come close. Below is the jQuery and HTML. So the class .allHover is what is triggering the hover effects. So I thought to remove the hover effect when the browser is less than 780px I would use a .removeClass method which would break the hover effect. The jQuery code below works, however when I resize the window to less than 780 px then refresh my browser the hover effect comes back and I dont want that. Is there something I can add to ensure the class .allHover doesnt come back when the page is less than 780px wide and the page is refreshed? Thank you in advance.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(window).on("load resize", function mobileViewUpdate() {
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    if (viewportWidth <= 780) {
      $(".allHover").removeClass("allHover").addClass("gallery-mobile");
    }
  });
</script>

<style>
  .stockDesign_image, .customDesign_image {
    width: 340px;
    height: 382px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  }
  div.allHover:hover .stockDesign_image, div.allHover:hover .customDesign_image {
    width: 360px;
  }
  
  .prodBoxes_header {
    background-color: #4c2e90;
  }
  
  div.allHover:hover .prodBoxes_header {
    background-color: #5E3EA6;
  }
  
  .prodBoxes_headerright {
    background-color: #ff6600;
  }
  
  div.allHover:hover .prodBoxes_headerright {
    background-color: #fb8332;
  }
  
  .viewAll_button {
    background-image: url(images/VIEW-ALL.png);
    width: 141px;
    height: 34px;
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin: 8px 5px 0 0;
  }
  div.allHover:hover .viewAll_button {
    background-position: 0 -34px;
  }
</style>

<div class="allHover">
  <div class="prodBoxes_header">
    <p class="medalHeader_text">CHOOSE FROM<br>1000+Insert designs...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="stockDesign_image"></div>
  <div class="prodBoxes_footer">
    <p class="footer_asLOWas">as low as <span class="asLOWas_price">$<?=($prod[1]->sale_price ?: $prod[1]->aslow_price);?></span></p>
    <div class="viewAll_button"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: seems to work fine for me if you load the window < 780px https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/bRMWaY

Comment: Im sorry. I found it also works fine for me too, however there is still one thing wrong that I didn't mention. So when you resize the window <780 px the hover effect goes away but if I go and resize that window again >780px it doesn't come back. Do I have to add something for that?

Comment: You probably just need an `else` condition for that. https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/bRMWaY

Comment: BTW, you can achieve all that with media queries, so you don't even need JS (Given your hover effect is done with CSS).

Comment: @MichaelCoker Thank you that worked. However I am getting an error on lines 6 & 8 of your JS code saying the '$allHover' is not defined. Is that something that I should be concerned about?

Comment: @Sveta I tried that a few times and couldn't understand why it didn't work or how to do it. Do you have any suggestions on how to do this using strictly CSS?

Comment: @Jenna check my pen - define `$allHover = $('.allHover');` before your `$(window).on('load resize'...` event handler

Comment: If you want to keep it in CSS, seems like you would just define your base styles outside of a media query @ 780px and overwrite them in the media query. Hard to tell you what to do since you didn't include any css. here's an example https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/OgZmKQ

Comment: @MichaelCoker I did define it, it must be my code editor. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Michael I went in and added my CSS. So I was having trouble because I wrapped 3 items in a div with a class of .allHover. The reason for that is I wanted to be able to hover over any of those 3 items and have all 3 hover effects trigger at once. I was having a hard time trying to cancel that out which is why I turned to jQuery.

Comment: is this what you're going for?  https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/EXLvqd

Comment: @Michael Yes it is! But unfortunately I coded the entire page using max-width instead of min-width because I didn't know better at the time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the hiding functionality also when the page is loaded. This can be done in the ready-function. I moved the hdiding funtionality to fucntion *checkViewportWidth* and call in both cases.

It seems that `on('load')` is not executed on page refresh.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function checkViewportWidth() {
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
     console.log(viewportWidth);
    if (viewportWidth <= 780) {
        $(".allHover").removeClass("allHover").addClass("gallery-mobile");
    }
  }

  $(window).on('load resize', function mobileViewUpdate() {
     checkViewportWidth();
  });

  checkViewportWidth();

});
```

Please see also [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vw2b904OpDwOhhAJNsuP?p=info)

Answer (score 0):

An example of how to accomplish this with media queries (given the hover effect is done with css.) The style will only work when screen size is <780.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 780px) {
    .allHover:hover {
...
    }
}
```

But if you need this to be js, you'll just need to add an else:

```
  function checkViewportWidth() {
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
     console.log(viewportWidth);
    if (viewportWidth <= 780) {
        $(".allHover").removeClass("allHover").addClass("gallery-mobile");
    }
    else{
        $(".allHover").addClass("allHover").removeClass("gallery-mobile");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A CSS only approach would be to add your `:hover` CSS in a `@media` query with `min-width: 780px` since you want `:hover` effects to fire when the window is > 780px.

```css
  @media (min-width: 780px) {
    div.allHover:hover .stockDesign_image,
    div.allHover:hover .customDesign_image {
      width: 360px;
    }
    div.allHover:hover .prodBoxes_header {
      background-color: #5E3EA6;
    }
    div.allHover:hover .prodBoxes_headerright {
      background-color: #fb8332;
    }
    div.allHover:hover .viewAll_button {
      background-position: 0 -34px;
    }
  }
  .stockDesign_image, .customDesign_image {
    width: 340px;
    height: 382px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  }
  
  .prodBoxes_header {
    background-color: #4c2e90;
  }
  
  .prodBoxes_headerright {
    background-color: #ff6600;
  }
  
  .viewAll_button {
    background-image: url(images/VIEW-ALL.png);
    width: 141px;
    height: 34px;
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin: 8px 5px 0 0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="allHover">
  <div class="prodBoxes_header">
    <p class="medalHeader_text">CHOOSE FROM<br>1000+Insert designs...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="stockDesign_image"></div>
  <div class="prodBoxes_footer">
    <p class="footer_asLOWas">as low as <span class="asLOWas_price">$<?=($prod[1]->sale_price ?: $prod[1]->aslow_price);?></span></p>
    <div class="viewAll_button"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```